# Transform sequence of characters to other sequence of characters

Tags: java

You have a string that represents a digital wave of "L" (low) and "H" (high). It is asked to show the wave that represents using `{ _ , |}`, as it is
shown in the following example: if it has the string `"HHHHLLLLHHHHHLLHHLLHH"`, its digital wave :

You can see something like this:

```
_ _ _ _         _ _ _ _ _     _ _     _ _
       |_ _ _ _|         |_ _|   |_ _|
```

each "H" or "L" represents a "_" or "-" and "|" when it changes to the other letter

Comment: Check the doc for String.replace(pattern, value)

Comment: Exactly what part of this are you having a problem with? Show us what you have done so far and explain what is not working.

Comment: seems more like someone's doing some homework with help of SO

Comment: See [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) about homework questions - there can be a bit of a stigma against them, but there's nothing wrong about posting them. However, as with all questions on SO, we do ask that you include **your own attempts**, as stated clearly on the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: Sorry is just that I tried a lot (all day) and don't think any of my attempts are worth sharing

Comment: Thanks Nadir didn't know about that

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic solution :

```
String wave = "HHHHLLLLHHHHHLLHHLLHH";
wave = wave.replaceAll("(H)(L)|(L)(H)", "$1|$2");//-------------(1)

String low = "";
for (char c : wave.toCharArray()) {
    if (c == 'H') {//-------------------------------------------(2)
        System.out.print("_ ");
        low += "  ";
    } else {
        System.out.print("  ");
        low += c;
    }
}
System.out.println();//----------------------------------------(3)
for (char c : low.toCharArray()) {
    switch (c) {//---------------------------------------------(4)
        case 'L':
            System.out.print("_");
            break;
        case '|':
            System.out.print("|");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.print(" ");
            break;
    }
}
```

The idea is :

1. put a bar `|` between each `LH` or `HL` to be `L|H` or `H|L`
2. loop over the character array, if it is equal to `H` print `_` and put to low variable a space else print a space and add the character to low
3. break line to print the low wave
4. if the character is `L` print `_` else if `|` print a bar else print a space

Answer (score 0):

In one line:

```
void printWave(String highLows) {
    String wave = highLows
        .replace("HL", "H|L")
        .replace("LH", "L|H")
        .replace('L', '_')
        .replace('H', '-');                                        // -|_
    System.out.println(wave);
}
```

In two lines:

```
void printWave(String highLows) {
    String wave = highLows
        .replace("HL", "H|L")
        .replace("LH", "L|H")
        .replace('L', '_')
        .replace('H', '-');                                        // -|_
    String line1 = wave.replaceAll("[^-]", " ").replace('-', '_'); // _
    String line2 = wave.replace('-', ' ');                         //  |_
    System.out.printf("%s%n%s%n", line1, line2);
}
```

Graphical using `─ ━ ┌ ┐ ┘ └`:

```
void printWave(String highLows) {
    final String HOR_H_OR_L = "\u2501"; // ━
    final String HOR_GAP = "\u2501";    // ─
    final String H_TO_L1 = "\u2510";    // ┐
    final String H_TO_L2 = "\u2514";    // └
    final String L_TO_H1 = "\u250C";    // ┌
    final String L_TO_H2 = "\u2518";    // ┘

    StringBuilder line1 = new StringBuilder(); 
    StringBuilder line2 = new StringBuilder();
    char[] chars = highLows.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length(); ++i) {
        char ch = chars[i];
        if (ch == 'H') {
            line1.append(HOR_H_OR_L);
            line2.append(' ');
        } else {
            line1.append(' ');
            line2.append(HOR_H_OR_L);
        }
        if (i == chars.length - 1 || ch == chars[i + 1]) {
            if (ch == 'H') {
                line1.append(HOR_GAP);
                line2.append(' ');
            } else {
                line1.append(' ');
                line2.append(HOR_GAP);
            }
        } else {
            if (ch == 'H') {
                line1.append(H_TO_L1);
                line2.append(H_TO_L2);
            } else {
                line1.append(L_TO_H1);
                line2.append(L_TO_H2);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("%s%n%s%n", line1, line2);
}
```